# How to calculate determinant of $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How can I calculate the determinant of the following matrix?

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda&&&a_0\\
-1&\ddots&&\vdots\\
&\ddots&\lambda&a_{n-2}\\
&&-1&\lambda+a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I've tried to calculate the determinants of the $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ ones and finally got something like

$$\det(A_n)=\lambda^n+\lambda^{n-1}a_{n-1}+\dots+a_0$$

But in order to prove this solution a mathematical induction would be necessary. Is there any more efficient way?

Comment: Looks like you want to compute the characteristic polynomial of a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). Try the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).